# how to make image in one div streach to whole page

Tags: html, reactjs, css, styles

I have a problem in css. In my page I want to add background image to a page which stretch to full height by changing its width (width need not be full). I count easily do it by background tag but the problem is i want to give opacity to the image, so I need to have two divs one with image and other with content and change position . But when I do it the image is only of height of view port but i want to it be equal to full page.

Can anyone please help me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body,
#back-img,
#content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%
}

#back-img {
  background: url(https://youngisland.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/aerial-optimized2.jpg);
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#content {
  aheight: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <h2 style="font-size:50px">MORE</h2>
</div>
<div id="back-img"></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide your css file contents?

Comment: Please can you clarify your question and create a [mcve] with your current code.  It is not very clear what your current problem or desired result is - eg *height of view port but i want to it be equal to full page* is the full page not the height of the viewport?  There doesn't seem to be enough content for it to be larger than the viewport

Comment: @tangoal I just updated question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is your problem but you have set a height of 100% on your body, this needs to be a min-height.  I would then make the body relative and then use right and bottom instead of width and height, whilst making your background size cover:

```css
 
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;   /* use min-height */
  position: relative;  /* move relative here */
}

#back-img {
  background: url(https://youngisland.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/aerial-optimized2.jpg) top left no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;   /* add this */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom:0;                 /* use bottom and right instead of height and width */
  right:0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#content {
  padding: 1px;       /* stop margins collapsing */
  height: 1000px;    /* for test and remove absolute positioning */
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <h2 style="font-size:50px">MORE</h2>
</div>
<div id="back-img"></div>
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Please accept the answer so others know the problem has been solved (click the tick to the top left of the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Add a fixed position to the element with a background image, and relative position to your content:

```
.content {
  position relative;
  z-index:2;
}

#back-img {
    background : url(https://youngisland.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/aerial-optimized2.jpg);
    background-position: cover;
    position:fixed; 
    right:0;
    bottom: 0;
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    z-index:1; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body, html {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#back-img {
  background: url(https://youngisland.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/aerial-optimized2.jpg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#content {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <h2 style="font-size:50px">MORE</h2>
</div>
<div id="back-img"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for your image: 
`background-size: cover;`